# Numbers Value Changes When Directly After the Backslash os.path.normpath(string)

Tags: python, path

I am using os.path.normpath and the values change when there are numbers directly after a backslash.

```
fileString = os.path.normpath("server:\Projects\05 Project Name\Data\20151021\Master.xlsx")
print fileString
```

Returns: server:\Projects\Project\Data�51021\MASTER_LIST.XLSX

Notice the '\05' disappeared and the '\20' turned into �.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: use `r"string"` or escape all your backslashes with `'\\'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to use a raw string literal:

```
fileString = os.path.normpath(r"server:\Projects\05 Project Name\Data\20151021\Master.xlsx")
#                             ^
```

The backslash character denotes an escape sequence in regular strings.

The other way around this is to either use forward slashes as path delimiters, or double backslashes:

```
"server:/Projects/05 Project Name/Data/20151021/Master.xlsx"
```

or

```
"server:\\Projects\\05 Project Name\\Data\\20151021\\Master.xlsx"
```